# Custom UIAlertView not resizing for keyboard after its 1st appearance

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a custom UIAlertVIew with 2 textFields that I am using to input values into. The first time that the customUIAlertVIew is displayed, the view is moved up to make room for the keyboard. 
[image]

This is unfortunately, not the case for each subsequent display. Each subsequent time, the alertView isn't moved up for the keyboard. 
[image]

I am looking for what is causing this problem, and how can I get around it in the future.

**EDIT:** Here is the code for how the custom UIAlertVIew is created. 
CustomUIAlertView.m

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.title = title;
        self.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Done"];
        [self setDelegate:self];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    NSArray *subViews = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.
    presentedViewController.view.subviews;

    if (subViews.count >1){
        UIView *presentedView = [subViews objectAtIndex:1];

        UILabel *player1Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 55, 130, 21)];
        player1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player 1 Score"];
       // player1Label.textInputMode = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

        player1Label.tag = 42;
        [presentedView addSubview:player1Label];

        UILabel *player2Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 75, 130, 21)];
        player2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player 2 Score"];
        player2Label.tag = 43;
        [presentedView addSubview:player2Label];

        self.p1ScoreField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 55, 80, 21)];
        self.p1ScoreField.placeholder= @"score";
        self.p1ScoreField.tag = 44;
        self.p1ScoreField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        self.p1ScoreField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.p1ScoreField.delegate = self;
        [self.p1ScoreField addTarget:self action:@selector(UITextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [presentedView addSubview:self.p1ScoreField];

       self.p2ScoreField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 75, 80, 21)];
        self.p2ScoreField.tag = 45;
        self.p2ScoreField.placeholder = @"score";
        self.p2ScoreField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        self.p2ScoreField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.p2ScoreField.delegate = self;
        [self.p2ScoreField addTarget:self action:@selector(UITextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [presentedView addSubview:self.p2ScoreField];


    }

}
```

View presented in a separate view Controller. Alloc/Init is called on alertView at the viewDidAppear method.

```
- (IBAction)addNewRoundButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [alertView show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding subviews to `UIAlertView` is **not supported** by Apple and is strongly discouraged.

You're better off using a regular view controller with custom modal presentation (look up `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`) or Googling a 3rd-party replacement.